# Python 3.7 : multiprocessing a for loop with shared variables

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

first a bit of context :

I'm trying to write down a python script to convert Image in greyscale (.tif) to a .jpeg with the so called ''jet'' colormap. I managed to do it with a for loop but it's a bit long for one image (millions of pixels to treat !), so I would like to use multiprocessing.

My problem here is that to convert each grey pixel into a coloured one I have to use two variables (the minimum value of light intensity ''min_img'' and an vector ''dx_cm'' to go from the initial grey scale to a 256 scale, corresponding to the jet colormap).

So to pass the information of ''min_img'' and ''dx_cm'' to the processes I try to use multiprocessing.Value() but in return I get the error :

```
RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

I tried many different things from different sources and no matter the version of my code I'm struggling with that error. So I'm sorry if my code isn't clean, I would be very grateful if someone could help me with that.

My non-working code :

```
import multiprocessing
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm


def fun(gr_list,dx,minp):

    dx_cmp = dx.value
    min_imgp = minp.value

    rgb_res=list()

    for i in range(len(gr_list)):
        rgb_res.extend(cm.jet(round(((gr_list[i]-min_imgp)/dx_cmp)-1))[0:-1])

    return rgb_res


if __name__ == '__main__':

    RGB_list=list()

    n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    img = Image.open(r'some_path_to_a.tif')

    Img_grey=list(img.getdata())

    dx_cm = multiprocessing.Value('d',(max(Img_grey)-min(Img_grey))/256)

    min_img = multiprocessing.Value('d',min(Img_grey))

    with multiprocessing.Pool(n) as p:

        RGB_list = list(p.map(fun, (Img_grey,dx_cm,min_img)))

    res = Image.frombytes("RGB", (img.size[0], img.size[1]), bytes([int(0.5 + 255*i) for i in RGB_list]))    

    res.save('rgb_file.jpg')
```

PS : Here is an example of the the initial for loop that I would like to parallelize :

```
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm


if __name__ == '__main__':

    img = Image.open(r'some_path_to_a.tif')

    Img_grey = list(img.getdata())

    dx_cm = (max(Img_grey)-min(Img_grey))/256

    min_img = min(Img_grey)

    Img_rgb = list()

    for i in range(len(Img_grey)):
        Img_rgb.extend(cm.jet(round(((Img_grey[i]-min_img)/dx_cm)-1))[0:-1])

    res = Image.frombytes("RGB", (img.size[0], img.size[1]), bytes([int(0.5 + 255*i) for i in Img_rgb]))    

    res.save('rgb_file.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fun` method is looping over some list, but in this case it will receive a "part", an item from your list, so it should return only the result of its processing.

I have changed the working code to run with multiprocessing.

As the `fun` method returns a list, the `p.map` will return a list of lists (a list of results) and that need to be flatten, were done with list `extends` method before.

Tried with process pool and thread pool multiprocessing, in my scenario there wasn't any performance gains.

- Process multiprocessing:

```py
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm
import multiprocessing


def fun(d):
    part, dx_cm, min_img = d
    return cm.jet(round(((part-min_img)/dx_cm)-1))[0:-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Image.open(r'a.tif')
    Img_grey = list(img.getdata())

    def Gen(img_data):
        dx_cm = (max(img_data)-min(img_data))/256
        min_img = min(img_data)
        for part in img_data:
            yield part, dx_cm, min_img

    n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n) as p:
        Img_rgb = [item for sublist in p.map(fun, Gen(Img_grey)) for item in sublist]

    res = Image.frombytes("RGB", (img.size[0], img.size[1]), bytes([int(0.5 + 255*i) for i in Img_rgb]))    
    res.save('b.jpg')
```

- Thread multiprocessing:

```py
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Image.open(r'a.tif')
    Img_grey = list(img.getdata())
    dx_cm = (max(Img_grey)-min(Img_grey))/256
    min_img = min(Img_grey)

    def fun(part):
        return cm.jet(round(((part-min_img)/dx_cm)-1))[0:-1]

    n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with ThreadPool(n) as p:
        Img_rgb = [item for sublist in p.map(fun, Img_grey) for item in sublist]

    res = Image.frombytes("RGB", (img.size[0], img.size[1]), bytes([int(0.5 + 255*i) for i in Img_rgb]))    
    res.save('b.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you for your corrections ! I ran several tests on my side as well on files of various sizes but no gains either ... In some cases, the initial for loop is faster than the multiprocessing script !
I understand the issue of communication overhead but even in case of images with huge size there isn't gain from multiprocessing, how could it be ?

Comment: I believe that the processing in the loop is too small get any valid performance gain

Comment: Sorry for necro-posting, but I am just curious about one thing. Did you write your answer and code and tried it with Python 3.7 ? For some obscure reason I must use Python 3.7.1 to build a virtual environment for a project, and the routine multiprocessing dance for CPU intensive tasks yields ... nothing. It's as if multiprocessing ceased to work for Python 3.7.1. Strange thing. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the computational burden isn't big enough for multiprocessing to be helpful.

Nevertheless, for those coming across this topic interested in the image processing part of my question, I found another much quicker way (15 to 20 x than previous method) to do the same thing without a for loop :

```
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

cm_jet = cm.get_cmap('jet')
img_src = Image.open(r'path to your grey image')
img_src.mode='I'

Img_grey = list(img_src.getdata())
max_img = max(Img_grey)
min_img = min(Img_grey)

rgb_array=np.uint8(cm_jet(((np.array(img_src)-min_img)/(max_img-min_img)))*255)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(rgb_array, cmap='jet')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax_plot = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

cbar=plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax_plot, ticks=[0,63.75,127.5,191.25,255])
dx_plot=(max_img-min_img)/255
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([str(min_img),str(round(min_img+63.75*dx_plot)),str(round(min_img+127.5*dx_plot)),str(round(min_img+191.25*dx_plot)), str(max_img)])

ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.savefig('test_jet.jpg', quality=95, dpi=1000)
```